# Python RegEx splitting street and number from adress

Tags: python, regex

I want to split street and number.

That is my current solution:

```py
matches = re.match(r'^(?<street>[^,]*?)[,\s]*(?P<number>\d[\w\s\-/]*$)', street_number)
```

but it is not working for some cases. If I have such examples:

```py
working_examples = [
    'Somestreet 1',
    'Somestreet1',
    'Somestreet1a',
    'Somestreet 1a',
    'Somestreet 1 a'
]
```

`print(matches.groupdict())` prints for first element of working_examples:

`{'street': 'Somestreet', 'number': '1'}`

However in that cases:

```py
not_working_examples = [
    'Some 1 street',
    'Some 1a street'
]
```

it prints

`{'street': 'Some ', 'number': '1 street'}`

and my goal is to have

`{'street': 'Some 1 street', 'number': None}`

Comment: Please explain the logic behind what the desired output should be, as well as the expected output for all provided examples.

Comment: I want to extract the number only when end of the string is a number, or a number with the ending a, b, c etc. for example 'E186street 1c'. Street should be 'E186Street' and number '1c'.

Comment: `^(.+?)(\d+\s*\w*)$`

Answer (score 1):

```
import re


examples = [
    'Somestreet 1',
    'Somestreet1',
    'Somestreet1a',
    'Somestreet 1a',
    'Somestreet 1 a',
    'Some 1 street',
    'Some 1a street'
]

for s in examples:
    matches = re.match(r'^(?P<street>.+?)[,\s]*(?P<number>\d\s?\w?)$', s)
    if matches:
        print(matches.groups())
    else:
        print s, "doesn't match"
```

**Output:**

```
('Somestreet', '1')
('Somestreet', '1')
('Somestreet', '1a')
('Somestreet', '1a')
('Somestreet', '1 a')
Some 1 street doesn't match
Some 1a street doesn't match
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/9tZvSd/1)